# How can I track user session throughout my site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I have a website with three pages. `blog.html` , `home.html` and `games.html` .

I am making an ajax request to my server on each page to track which pages the user has visited.

I am wondering, what would be the best way to track user `sessions`. For example, my friend Steve, goes on to my website at `home.html` then decides to go to `games.html` then finally decides to go to `blog.html` then shut-down his computer.

That would be like the whole 'session' of a user where I am group the pageviews. What would be the best practice for implementing this?

Thank you in advance!

Idea: One Idea is to track the session using the javascript reffered URL. Is this a good method?

Comment: Read about [PHP sessions](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: It sounds to me you're trying to solve a solved problem. Have you looked into tools such as Google Analytics?

Comment: Yes I have heard about them however I would rather use my own system.

Comment: What about using http://piwik.org/ (on your own server) then?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I was working on the past few days on this project and it is a great learning experience for me. I'm hoping to implement this myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [PHP sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) which are an out-of-the-box solution for this common problem.

When you really want to build your own as an education exercise, this is how they work:

When a user visits the website, the PHP script checks if a [cookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) has been set. When there isn't a cookie, it auto-generates a random ID and writes it to the cookie. These SessionIDs and all information about the state of the users session are saved server-sided. When you have a database, you can store it there, but you can also use files when you want to.

The sessionIDs should be unique to avoid duplicates and impossible to guess so that no user can forge their sessionID to steal the identity of another user. So your generation algorithm for the sessionIDs should include both the current time (to the millisecond) and a random number.

When the user has cookies disabled, you can still track them by putting their SessionID as a [GET-argument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) into every link on your website. When the users SessionID is 1f6fe6894d32c5, for example, the url `href="games.php"` becomes `href="games.php?sid=1f6fe6894d32c5`.

When you use the url-method you should also bind sessionIDs to IP addresses, because when a user posts a link to your website, they might forget to remove their sessionID from the URL and your website would believe everyone who clicks the link is the same user. But even when you do check IPs, it could still lead to unintentional (or intentional) session stealing between users behind the same proxy or NAT router. So do not use URL sessionIDs for anything where security matters.

Comment: putting session id´s in links like this works but could be a problem , especially on public/shared computers.

Comment: @RainerPlumer There is no technology yet which can detect when the user stands up and somebody else takes their place. Unless you have access to their webcam, of course.

Comment: Interesting! Do these SESSION cookies delete after the user closes the webpage?

Comment: @Highschooler No, they don't. But they usually have a timeout-value after which the browser will delete them automatically. You should also delete them automatically on the server after a while to avoid running out of storage.

Comment: Hmm, so if a user goes on my site and clicks some links, then decides to close the browser, and then go back to my site and click links, it will appear as one session?

Comment: @Highschooler yes, because the session-handling is server-sided. After the server has served a HTML document, it doesn't know what the user does with it. The server isn't notified when the user closes the browser.

Comment: @Highschooler: Cookies come in two varieties: session cookies, which will expire when the browser session ends (e.g. the browser exits); and cookies with timed expiry which will expire at a given time. When you set a cookie, you determine what kind it is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you simply want to tack the pages user has visited, save each visit in a database with a date/timestamp + ip and any other information you need.

Then, you can later use this information to see when the user visited any specific sites. 
You can also track the links user came from by adding an extra parameter to your links, i.e if you have 2 links to your home page on page2, then those links could look like this
href="home.php?ref=link2" and you could store this info in database as well.

There are many ways to do this, but in the end, i would recommend using ready made software as suggested in comments.

Comment: IPs are no way to identify users. You sometimes have thousands of people surfing behind the same proxy server.

Comment: i didnt suggest it was for ID, but as extra information which can come in handy later...eg for location purposes. For identification, a login system would be needed...and in that case you would store the user id

Comment: This is what I am doing right now but I'm trying to figure out how I can 'group' these page views into sessions.

Comment: As mentioned in the above answer, you can use PHP sessions to group user activities, and store your data with session_id included.